# Graphing a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am getting a graph, but its not what I was think I would get.

Equation: $\frac{dR(t)}{dt}=\gamma\,\tau-\mu \,R(t)$

This is the code I used:

```
R[t_, γ_, τ_, μ_] := R[t, γ, τ, μ] = γ τ - μ R[t - 1, γ, τ, μ]

R[0, γ_, τ_, μ_] = 2.5 10^11

ListPlot[Table [R[t, 1.36, 0.2, 0.072], {t, 0, 50}], Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
```

I am getting a graph, but not exactly what I was expecting, not sure, if is my equation or if I could use a different code. I was looking for something that would have more of a parabolic shape. Or a linear increase.

Any suggestions or is this what I should expect based on my equation/values.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it's unclear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make it clear and specific, explain how your code relates with your equation, and make it explicitly about Wolfram Mathematica programming. remember to keep your code well [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) 
Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Kuba Now I understand, the OP wrote h(er)is ODE as a recursive equation. And the issue in h(er)is code can be fixed by including `PlotRange->All` in `ListPlot`.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't solve the ode using `DSolve` and then plot its solution?

```
ode = R'[t] == g*tau - mu*R[t];
sol = DSolve[{ode, R[0] == 2.5 10^11}, R[t], t]
Plot[R[t] /. sol /. {g -> 1.36, tau -> 0.2, mu -> 0.072}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

You just need to include `PlotRange -> All`,

```
ListPlot[Table[R[t, 1.36, 0.2, 0.072], {t, 0, 50}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh okay, yes that works better. Okay thank you!